# Is Adobe Animate CC suitable for these animations?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, adobe-flash, adobe-after-effects

I have noticed many people on Dribbble and Behance create animations such as the one below in Illustrator and then animate it in After Effects.

I need to create similar animations, as well in an isometric view, for game assets. Is Animate CC, (formally known as Flash), a suitable option?

[image]

Sailor Walk Animation - [Jonathan Dahl](https://www.behance.net/jdahl)

Comment: What kind of game? A flash browser game, an HTML game on mobile, a game in an engine like Unity, ... The choice of software depends heavily on the technology I think

Comment: Any animation app worth its salt can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In addition, Animate / Flash, is more lightweight and comfortable for those things than After Effects.